# How inherit DataContext?

Tags: wpf, f#, datacontext

please note that I using F# that specific with WPF.  What should do to set DataContext of childs of the control at any depth? Particulary how set the data context to control with name "TargetControl". Problem context:

App.xaml:

```xml
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        >
    <Frame Name="Frame" Source="MainWindow.xaml" />
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="mainTab">
            <!-- Tests work area -->
            <TabItem Header="Проверка проекта">
                <Frame Source="TestsPropagate.xaml" />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

***TestsPropagate.xaml***

```xml
<UserControl 
    Name="TargetControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=testField}" />
</UserControl>
```

My bootloader to start this cap:

```
[<STAThread>]
[<EntryPoint>]
let main(_) = //(new Application()).Run(Application.Current) //mainWindowViewModel)
    OFTD.DOM.ExtraEntities.Verification.EnitiesInitializer.InitializeReaders()
    let app = new Application()
    let view = Application.LoadComponent( new System.Uri("App.xaml", UriKind.Relative) ) :?> Window

    let vm = new AppViewModel() // is data context to TargetControl    
    app.Run(view)
```

Comment: Wow, WPF and F#, you're brave :)

Comment: Now I use F# only in kernel of program and to implement view model. Then I expanding view model in C# code(for code behind) and use WPF in C# with F#'s view model:)

Answer (score 1):

Not super-sure about the fsharp syntax, but this should make sense:

```
let vm = new AppViewModel() // is data context to TargetControl    
view.DataContext <- vm
app.Run(view)
```

Comment: No, DataContext to UserControl with the name "TargetControl" not inherited DataContext from view. Note that used Source field on Frame control

Comment: well, I don't see anywhere in your code where you would associate your DataContext with any Visual, hence my answer

Comment: ok, my code has this behavior. What should do to set DataContext of childs of the `view` at any depth?